# Change the width of the images according to aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am building a comic reading website. I got a problem with displaying images. Most of my images are having the aspect ratio of 2/3. Means 1000x1500. So I am displaying them with below css rules. But there are some images like double page images. So when the css rule `max-width=728px` is applied this 4/3 raito image can't read anything. So basically I want to change the css rule for `max-width=728px` when the user came across to 4/3 ratio images. Css rule `max_width=728px` still have to apply the 2/3 ratio images but when the ratio changes to 4/3 it has to be `max-width=1250px`. What do i need to do for solving this? It is related to css or need some javascript. This manga website has this future I think. Double page images are displaying width of ~1300 and when i shrink the browser its javascript updating the width and height.

Example:http://www.mangaeden.com/en/en-manga/berserk/344/17/
My website:http://mangabozok.com/oku/Berserk/346/5

HTML:

```
<div class="gnc02">
<img src="paths">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gnc02 img {
     display:block;
     margin:auto;
     max-width: 728px;
     height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following style:

```
.gnc02 img
{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1250px;
    max-height: 1092px;
}
```

For the 2:3 images, the `max-height` applies and restricts the width to 728 pixels. For the 4:3 images, the `max-width` applies and restricts the width to 1250 pixels.

```css
.gnc02 img
{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1250px;
    max-height: 1092px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gnc02">
  <img src="http://cdn.mangaeden.com/mangasimg/82/82018e71734a3893bc60f2e3a5df4520b1343c862ef09e3c7b30fd1d.jpg" />
</div>
<br/>
<div class="gnc02">
  <img src="http://cdn.mangaeden.com/mangasimg/d6/d6afc1d18c0c08d6129f121a3531f47933d8fdbccca0ea7f78ed10e8.jpg" />
</div>
```

Note: when running the code snippet, you should switch to "Full page" mode.

Answer (score 3):

```
.gnc02 {
    max-width: 728px;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}

.gnc02 img {
    max-width: 100%;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Who would of think that  it could be this simple.

Comment: I applied it but its not working. Could you look at my webite? http://mangabozok.com:8080/oku/Berserk/346/5

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
.gnc02 {
    width: 99% !important;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    }
    .gnc02 img {
        max-width: 100%;
      }
```

```html
 
    <div class="gnc02">
      <img src="http://cdn.mangaeden.com/mangasimg/82/82018e71734a3893bc60f2e3a5df4520b1343c862ef09e3c7b30fd1d.jpg" />
    </div>
```

this code is used for responsive designing. I think this may help you in any type of image or the size of the image.